# Как получить доступ к объекту другого класса?

Tags: php, ооп, codeigniter

Есть такой вопрос...
В системе реализовано 2 класса, один **Upload** - для загрузки файлов, второй - **Article** - для управления сущностью "Статьи".
В классе **Upload** есть переменная **$files**, которая содержит информацию о загруженных файлах.

Когда пользователь заполняет форму добавления статьи, ему дозволено загрузить несколько изображений, которые отправляются на сервер Ajax'ом файлу Upload.php.
Иначе говоря, изображения грузятся вперед контента статьи, а далее, после сабмита формы, добавляется уже содержимое формы (класс Article).

Так вот, как получить доступ из класса *Article* к переменной **$files**, чтобы в одном потоке добавить информацию в БД?
Проблема в том, что *Article*, *Upload* - это 2 контроллера, использую Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk)](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk) -

> ему дозволено загрузить несколько изображений, которые отправляются на сервер Ajax'ом файлу Upload.php

Ответ сервера сделайте в виде json-массива с ссылками на файлы и прикрепите к основной форме статьи при помощи JS. На момент отправки статьи, "сущность" Upload уже не существует, так как запрос отработает и вернет результат фронтэнду.

Comment: Об этой идеи подумал изначально, но что, если пользователь заменит пути к файлам в форме?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, ну, у вас должна же быть повторная отправка файлов. Эта проблема не формы статьи, а формы загрузки файлов, она должна предоставлять актуальную информацию об изменении.

Comment: Какая повторная отправка файлов? Разве не достаточно один раз?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk 

> но что если пользователь заменит пути к файлам в форме? 

Что вы подразумеваете под этой фразой?

Comment: Т.е. Ajax возвращает в форму (скрытое поля input) пути к загруженным картинкам на сервере. Тогда злой пользователь может заменить эти пути на внешние и отправить форму на добавление.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, ок, возвращайте id файлов, в чем проблема?